# Enforcing event wiring Event-based Asynchronous Pattern

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous

I'm implementing the aforementioned pattern in an existing synchronous class, and I'm wondering if it's advisable to enforce wiring of the MethodNameComplete event as follows:

```
public event AsyncEventHandler MethodNameCompleted;

public void MethodNameAsync()
{
    if (MethodNameCompleted == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(
            "MethodNameCompleted must be wired before calling MethodNameAsync");
    }

    //perform async task...
}
```

Unfortunately neither the pattern overview (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) or the linked implementation pages advise on this.

Comment: Good question. By switching to the `Task`-based model the question becomes moot though. Maybe something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately we're targeting .NET 4.0 for legacy OS users, and I believe there's no built-in implementation of async/await in anything below .NET 4.5

Comment: You can use tasks without await. It is still more convenient than async events (they are about the worst possible model, even ranking below IAsyncResult).

Comment: Yes, I realise that now :-) My event based implementation actually wrapped a Task, and is now a lot simpler. Sometimes these things take a while to grok. If you want to suggest use of TAP as a solution I'll happily pick it as the answer.